# DrRacket Scheme Contract Violation

Tags: scheme, racket

Not sure why  I am getting the contract violation in DrRacket.

```
(define (range rlist)
(display 'ran)
(let ([start (car  rlist)]
    [step  (cdr  rlist)]
    [end   (cddr rlist)])
(cond [(< start end)
      (set (car rlist) (+ (car rlist) (cdr rlist)))
      (cons start (range rlist))
      ]
     )
))
```

I get

```
<: contract violation
  expected: real?
  given: '(7)
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments.:
```

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong near the code this message refers to, which you failed to identify.

Answer (score 1):

I's assuming rlist is supposed to be a list of numbers.

However in your `let` bindings you bind `step` and `end` to lists instead of a number in the list.

You can't compare `start` which I'm assuming to be a number with `end`  which was bound with the value '(7)

You are still missing an else case, what if start is not less than end?

Additionally `(set (car rlist) ...) isn't going to work it just isn't. You can only`set!` variables, not values. Just pass the change in the recursive call. Define an inner producrue (define or let loop) that takes three arguments if you don't want the overhead of building a list on each recursion.

```
(define (range rlist)
  (display 'ran)
  (let ([start (car  rlist)]
        [step  (cadr  rlist)]
        [end   (caddr rlist)])
     (cond [(< start end)
            (cons start 
                  (range (list (+ start step)
                               step
                               stop)))]
            [else '()])))
```

Might be closer to what you want